# ESlint warns for function keyword in anonymous and doesnt allow assignment to arguments within the function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, eslint

I have a code to rename the keys of object available with me using lodash transform as:

```
const replaceKeysDeep = (obj, keysMap) => { 
  return transform(obj, function(result, value, key){
    const currentKey = keysMap[key] || key;
    result[currentKey] = isObject(value) ? replaceKeysDeep(value, keysMap) : value;
  });
};
```

I had the above implementation changed to

```
const replaceKeysDeep = (obj, keysMap) => { 
  return transform(obj, (result, value, key) => {
    const currentKey = keysMap[key] || key;
    result[currentKey] = isObject(value) ? replaceKeysDeep(value, keysMap) : value;
  });
};
const newKeys = {
          abs: 'myname',
          tyu: 'yourname'
};
const someObjectContainingKeys = {
          abs: 'something',
          tyu: 'somethingelse'
};
const finalTimePointCalc = replaceKeysDeep(someObjectContainingKeys, newKeys);
```

the implementation is changed because eslint was prompting for the keyword "function", but now it prompts me for Assignment to property of function parameter

Here i dont want to suppress the ESLINT warnings but to get it right for execution.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into source code([`trasnform()`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L13789) calls [`baseForOwn()`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L2995) that is actually [`baseFor()`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L2973) that is generated by [`createBaseFor()`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L4902)) I believe there is no chance to fit both requirements(consuming lodash's `transform()` for readability and satisfy eslint's [`no-param-reassign`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign)).

Unlike `Array.prototype.reduce` `transform()` does not allow you returning accumulator explicitly(you can see it in `createBaseFor()` code).

So there are just few solutions: either write your own code for `transform()`. Or you can suppress eslint rule on per-line/per-file/global basis to allow modifying function arguments' props with `props: false`(see [`no-param-reassign` docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) for details)

Comment: thats heartbreaking....any ways.. thanks for the explanation on why it behaves so... I will work towards my own solution

Comment: I am still hoping for someone to throw more insight on this.. by the way please do upvote my question, if you find some knowledge can be accumulated by other SOs from here, associated with your findings